# How can I use str_getcsv() and ignore commas between quotes?

Tags: php, regex, csv

Here's my current code.

```
<?php$da_data = $_POST['dadata'];
$da_data = htmlspecialchars($da_data, ENT_QUOTES);
$da_data = str_replace('&lt;', '', $da_data);
$da_data = str_replace("&gt;", '', $da_data);
$da_data = str_getcsv($da_data,  ",", "'");
print_r($da_data);
?>
```

Example data:

```
"Bill, Rose Mary" <bill@co.bill.ca.us>,"asasd, test" <test@co.test.ca.us>,
```

it's spitting out

```
Array (
[0] => \"Bill
[1] => Rose Mary\" bill@co.bill.ca.us
[2] => \"asasd
[3] => test\" test@co.test.ca.us
[4] =>
)
```

I'd like to have the name and email together opposed to separated. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

```
$da_data = str_getcsv($da_data,  ",", "'");
//                                     ^
```

would read this like you want:

```
'Bill, Rose Mary' <bill@co.bill.ca.us>,'asasd, test' <test@co.test.ca.us>,
^               ^                      ^           ^
```

But you don't use single quotes in your CSV file like you specified in your `str_getcsv` call. It's `"`:

```
$da_data = str_getcsv($da_data,  ',', '"');
//                                     ^

var_dump($da_data);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(36) "Bill, Rose Mary <bill@co.bill.ca.us>"
  [1]=>
  string(32) "asasd, test <test@co.test.ca.us>"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/124469)

**Please do note that it removes your `"` as they're actually supposed to be enclosing the *entire* string.**

On a completely different note, to make sure that you get the right data you should transform your CSV file into the following:

```
"Bill, Rose Mary <bill@co.bill.ca.us>","asasd, test <test@co.test.ca.us>",
^                                    ^ ^                                ^
```

Comment: If he changed it to `"` would it read the first field like `"Bill, Rose Mary" <bill@co.bill.ca.us>` ?

Comment: I'm getting close but I think I'm having an issue with the proper encoding. here's it with ENT_NOQUOTES http://i.imgur.com/Uxth0Cc.png and here's it with ENT_QUOTES http://i.imgur.com/90f2zb5.png . I should note that the data I'm inputting isn't exactly a csv. It's data that I pulled from gmail's CC box and inputted into via an html form. Is there something I need to do to properly encode it?

Comment: there also seems to be a &nbsp; being generated http://imgur.com/XD6e4ZB . I think there's some sort of encoding issue I'm missing. Probably because I don't know much about encoding!

Comment: @Kenny What's your actual CSV data? Can you update your question with it?

Comment: @h2ooooooo the data is actual email addresses from a non profit I'm helping out. it's probably not a good idea to post it here. that's why I used dummy text. I sent you an email with the data though.